# Exception with DataOutputStream but not PrintWriter

Tags: java, android, sockets, dataoutputstream

I have developed a basic java client/server using sockets.  Using `PrintWriter`, everything works as expected.  But, if I change the server output method to `DataOutputStream`, the `InputStream` on the client is 0 length, and it eventually times out.

> Server side

It works when I use (1):

```
bufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(newOutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);                  
bufferOut.println(response);
```

But not when I use (2):

```
bufferOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
bufferOut.write(response.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
```

The client has an `InputStream` length = 0

The only exceptions encountered are when the client times out and closes the socket - the server then throws a broken pipe exception.

> Client side

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
String read = bufferIn.readLine();
```

What am I not understanding? Is there something missing?  What else can I provide to help?

**Edit**

Updated client side:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
int length = dis.available();                   

// create buffer
byte[] buf = new byte[length];                  
// read the full data into the buffer
dis.readFully(buf);

Log.d(TAG,  "buffer length: "+buf.length);

// for each byte in the buffer
for (byte b:buf){
    // convert byte to char
    char c = (char)b;                      
    // append 
    message_string += c;
}
```

Still not getting data back with (2) - logcat buf.length = 0

Comment: The `PrintWriter` will automatically flush the data while the `DataInputStream` will not, add a `bufferOut.flush()` call after you write something to the stream, see if that helps. Also `DataInputStream.readLine()` is deprecated, you should use some other read method.

Answer (score 0):

`println()` appends a line terminator. `write()` does not. `readLine()` blocks until a line terminator is read, or EOS or an exception occurs.

If you're using `readLine()` at one end, you should be using `BufferedInputStream.readLine(),`, and a `Writer` at the other end, not `DataOutputStream.`

Comment: What should I use on the client - I need to handle raw ASCII

Comment: If you're sending non-character data you should use `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. If you're in control of both ends you can use `readUTF()` and `writeUTF()` instead of lines.